# PHP, stdClass, select elements contains specifed element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, stdclass

I have an stClass object like this:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#44 (2) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(3232)
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "sibling"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#43 (2) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(32323)
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "sibling"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#42 (2) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(3213)
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "grandchild"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#41 (3) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(-680411188)
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "parent"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#40 (3) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(-580189276)
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "parent"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#39 (2) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(3213)
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "sibling"
  }
}
```

How can I get elements with specified value of type element?
For example, if I select "parent", I wanna get this:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#41 (3) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(-680411188)
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "parent"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#40 (3) {
    ["uid"]=>
    int(-580189276)
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "parent"
  }
}
```

I know, how to write it with "**foreach**" and "**if**", but I hope that there is another way. Thanks

Comment: Where/how are you getting the data from?

Comment: @Pinoniq it's an open API of VK.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer object is in fact, an array in disguise. You can convert it to a real array by typecasting:

```
$arr = (array)$obj;
```

Then you can use:

```
$filtered = array_filter(
    $arr,
    function($item) {
        return $item->type == 'parent';
    }
);
```

to get an array that contains only the objects you need.