# How to filter a two dimensional array by value

Tags: php, arrays

How would I create a function that filters a two dimensional array by value?

Given the following array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => CarEnquiry
            [status] => NEW
            [appointment] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => CarEnquiry
            [status] => CALL1
            [appointment] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => Finance
            [status] => CALL2
            [appointment] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => Partex
            [status] => CALL3
            [appointment] => 0
        )
```

How would I filter the array to only show those arrays that contain a specific value in the `name` key? For example `name = 'CarEnquiry'`.

The resulting output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => CarEnquiry
            [status] => NEW
            [appointment] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [interval] => 2014-10-26
            [leads] => 0
            [name] => CarEnquiry
            [status] => CALL1
            [appointment] => 0
        )

    )
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the search value should be interchangeable - i.e. `name = 'CarEnquiry'` or `name = 'Finance'`.

Comment: Use `array_filter()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: You know that in your example, none of the `name` properties equal the string `"CarEnquiry"`. They are of the *class* `CarEnquiry`.

Comment: I answered the exact same question several hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27440026/4265352

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use PHP's [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function with a callback.

```
$new = array_filter($arr, function ($var) {
    return ($var['name'] == 'CarEnquiry');
});
```

Edit: If it needs to be interchangeable, you can modify the code slightly:

```
$filterBy = 'CarEnquiry'; // or Finance etc.

$new = array_filter($arr, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return ($var['name'] == $filterBy);
});
```

Comment: @Tobias Yes, you could do. 

`$new = array_filter($arr, function ($var) use ( $filterBy1, $filterBy2 ) { return ($var['name'] == $filterBy1 || $var['name'] == $filterBy2 ) });`

Comment: With reindexing (start at 0) :
`$new = array_values(array_filter($arr, function ($var) {
    return ($var['name'] == 'CarEnquiry');
}));`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make this a generic function use this:

```
function filterArrayByKeyValue($array, $key, $keyValue)
{
    return array_filter($array, function($value) use ($key, $keyValue) {
       return $value[$key] == $keyValue; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, what is the reserved word 'use' for? I usually use it to refer to namespaces

Comment: @Daniele, the keywork 'use' transfer the variables into the callback function. In this case, $key and $keyValue that is 'outside' the callback will be accessible inside the callback.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php



    function filter_array($array,$term){
        $matches = array();
        foreach($array as $a){
            if($a['name'] == $term)
                $matches[]=$a;
        }
        return $matches;
    }

    $new_array = filter_array($your_array,'CarEnquiry');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Above examples are using the exact word match, here is a simple example for filtering array to find imprecise "name" match.

```
  $options = array_filter($options, function ($option) use ($name) {
    return strpos(strtolower($option['text']), strtolower($name)) !== FALSE;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` is the function you need. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Give it a filtering function like this:

```
function my_filter($elt) {
    return $elt['name'] == 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function multi_array_search_with_condition($array, $condition)
{
    $foundItems = array();

    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        $find = TRUE;
        foreach($condition as $key => $value)
        {
            if(isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $value)
            {
                $find = TRUE;
            } else {
                $find = FALSE;
            }
        }
        if($find)
        {
            array_push($foundItems, $item);
        }
    }
    return $foundItems;
}
```

This my function can use about this problem. You can use:

```
$filtered = multi_array_search_with_condition(
   $array,
   array('name' => 'CarEnquiry')
);
```

This will get your filtered items from your 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Why bother with the temporary `true` / `false` declaration?  I would not recommend this long-winded solution.  (A good piece to include would be a `break`)