# Remove array element by checking a value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
[0=>['classId'=>2,'Name'=>'John'],1=>['classId'=>3,'Name'=>'Doe'],2=>['classId'=>4,'Name'=>'Stayne']]
```

I need to remove the elements with classId 2 or 4 from array and the expected result should be

```
[0=>['classId'=>3,'Name'=>'Doe']]
```

How will i achieve this without using a loop.Hope someone can help

Comment: Just loop thorough and unset?

Comment: @Steven Without using a loop

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that. Why without a loop?

Comment: You can't do it without a loop. If you mean how to do it with built-in PHP functions, that's a different thing. But even those will internally loop.

Comment: @El_Vanja I can use array functions in php.I know it still use loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a two dimensional array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447923/how-to-filter-a-two-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through an array?

Comment: Then just: `array_filter($array, function($item){return $item["classId"] !== 2;});`

Comment: @Steven I have edited my question ..Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` in conjunction with `in_array`.

```
$array = [0=>['classId'=>2,'Name'=>'John'],1=>['classId'=>3,'Name'=>'Doe'],2=>['classId'=>4,'Name'=>'Stayne']];

var_dump(

    array_filter($array, function($item){return !in_array($item["classId"], [2,4]);})

);
```

### Explanation

**`array_filter`**

Removes elements from the array if the call-back function returns false.

**`in_array`**

Searches an array for a value; returns boolean true/false if the value is (not)found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach array as $k => $v{
    if ($v['classId'] == 2){
        unset(array[$k]);
    }
}
```

I just saw your edit, you could use array_filter like so:

```
function class_filter($arr){
    return ($arr['classId'] == "whatever");
}
array_filter($arr, "class_filter");
```

Note: you'll still need to loop through a multi-dimensional array I believe.