# How to get Distinct array values based on another column

Tags: php, arrays

I have this sample array - as returned from a database query:

```
array (size=107)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2310]
      public 'country' => string 'Canada' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Ontario' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Toronto' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'high' (length=6)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2311]
      public 'country' => string 'Canada' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Ontario' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Barrie' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'low' (length=6)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[2311]
      public 'country' => string 'Canada' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Nova Scotia' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Halifax' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'medium' (length=6)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[2312]
      public 'country' => string 'USA' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'California' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Los Angeles' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'high' (length=6)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[2313]
      public 'country' => string 'USA' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Ohio' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Dayton' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'low' (length=6)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[2314]
      public 'country' => string 'USA' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Illinois' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Chicago' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'high' (length=6)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[2315]
      public 'country' => string 'USA' (length=10)
      public 'province' => string 'Illinois' (length=14)
      public 'city' => string 'Aurora' (length=14)
      public 'living_cost' => string 'med' (length=6)
```

I'd like to get the unique Country values, so:

- Canada
- USA

And then for each, I'd like to list the province and cities, for example:

- Canada

  - Ontario

    - Toronto
    - Barrie

USA

- California

  - Los Angeles
- Illinois

  - Chicago
  - Aurora

I figured out how to get the unique countries, using:

```
$countries = array_unique(array_column($db_data, 'country'));
```

But not sure how to use the country array to now parse the database result to get the unique province and cities.

Please keep in mind, I'm not trying to get the unique values of each field - I need to first filter by the country so I can still relate the provinces and cities back to the country.

In other words: for each country, I want to retrieve a list of all provinces and all cities.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the answers provided are not understanding the issue at hand.  Basically, I need to answer the questions:  "what are the all unique provinces" for Canada, or "what are the unique cities for USA".  Meaning, if provided the country, how do I go about parsing the original data to retrieve the unique cities or provinces for that country.

Answer (score 0):

```
$city1 = new stdClass();
$city1->country = 'Canada';
$city1->province = 'Ontario';
$city1->city = 'Toronto';
$city1->living_cost = 'high';

$city2 = new stdClass();
$city2->country = 'Canada';
$city2->province = 'Ontario';
$city2->city = 'Barrie';
$city2->living_cost = 'low';

$city3 = new stdClass();
$city3->country = 'Canada';
$city3->province = 'Nova Scotia';
$city3->city = 'Halifax';
$city3->living_cost = 'medium';

$city4 = new stdClass();
$city4->country = 'USA';
$city4->province = 'California';
$city4->city = 'Los Angeles';
$city4->living_cost = 'high';

$city5 = new stdClass();
$city5->country = 'USA';
$city5->province = 'Ohio';
$city5->city = 'Dayton';
$city5->living_cost = 'low';

$city6 = new stdClass();
$city6->country = 'USA';
$city6->province = 'Illinois';
$city6->city = 'Chicago';
$city6->living_cost = 'high';

$city7 = new stdClass();
$city7->country = 'USA';
$city7->province = 'Illinois';
$city7->city = 'Aurora';
$city7->living_cost = 'medium';

$data = [ $city1, $city2, $city3, $city4, $city5, $city6, $city7 ];

$result = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
  $country = $item->country;
  $province = $item->province;
  $city = $item->city;
  $result[$country][$province][$city] = $item;
}


print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try somthing like this
The $array should be your array result from database.

```
$array = array(

  0 =>  [

    'city' => 'title 1',
    'country' => 'green',
    'province' => 'green'
  ],
  1=> [

        'city' => 'title 1',
    'country' => 'green',
    'province' => 'green'
   ],
   2 => [

         'city' => 'title 1',
    'country' => 'green',
    'province' => 'green'
   ]
);


$uniqueEntries = array();


for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){

    $entry = $array[$i];
    $country = $entry["country"];
    $province = $entry["province"];
    $city = $entry["city"];
    $key = $country . "" . $province . "" .$city;

    $uniqueEntries[$key] = $entry;

}
```

Finally iterate the unique entries array

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447923/how-to-filter-a-two-dimensional-array-by-value) here, this seems to work for me:

```
   $countries = array_unique(array_column($db_data, 'country'));

    foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
        $subset = array_filter($db_data, function ($obj) use ($country) {
            return ($obj->country == $country);
        });

        $cities = array_unique(array_column($subset, 'cities'));

        echo $country. "<br>";
        echo print_r($cities) . '<br><br>';
    }
```

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this, but it seems to work.